# Memory error Using intertool in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

i write a programme that i input 10 for example and it find the odd number first and the even number and put them in a list [1,3,5,7,9,2,4,6,8,10] and input another number which choose the number in the list for example 3 so it print 5 and so on so i write a code like that

```
from itertools import count
n,y=map(int, raw_input().split()) # Input the 2 numbers 
listaa=[0,] # list to save 
for x in count(1,1):
   if x%2!=0:
      listaa.append(x)
   if x==n:
       break
for h in count(1,1):
   if h%2==0:
      listaa.append(h)
   if h==n:
      break
res=listaa[y]
print res # it print the number that is in the Array or list
```

but when i submit the code on the online judge it try this number 1000000000000 500000000001 so it get RUNTIME_ERROR then i try this on my eclipse i get Memory Error Note i first try the Xrange but i get error when i search found the Generator so i try it and use count instead of Xrange  note the Run time limit for each test case is 1 second

Comment: Why build lists? If all you want is the number at a given position, a little math will do.

Comment: please tell me how to do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you cannot solve this problem using that approach because the list is very big also it will time limit the test case you suggested 1000000000000 500000000001 contains approximately 4*10^12 numbers which needs more than a terabyte of ram.
so don't use a list use a math formula instead.

sample code

```
n,y=map(int, raw_input().split())
first_odd = 1
last_odd = n if n%2 == 1 else n-1
n_odd = (last_odd-first_odd)/2 + 1
if y <= n_odd:
    print first_odd + 2*(y-1)
else:
    y -= n_odd
    print 2+2*(y-1)
```

Comment: You are Right The problem is math but Can you tell me whats the equation that can i work to get the solution

Comment: ok let a be the first odd number in the list b the last odd number. n_odd = b-a+1 if y <= n_odd then it's an odd number with value a+(y-1)*2. the same can be applied to even numbers but the index of even number will be y-n_odd

Comment: You can also implement Eratosthenes Sieve. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes

Comment: give me the problem link then

Comment: check the edit the code is working I tried to submit it and it got accepted